# how to target outer div based on url

Tags: html, css

I have html script like :

```
<html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
        <div id="div1"></div>

        <div id="div2"></div>
     </body>
</html>
```

then I want to access the div by url, if url is:

> example.com#div1

I want to hide `div2` and if url is:

> example.com#div2

then I want to hide `div1`

How do I solve that with `css`?

Comment: CSS only? Not sure if thats possible

Comment: you mean css and javascript

Comment: CSS can't see your url, but I bet you could set anchor targets, an if your divs were 100% window height it would appear as if one was hidden.

Comment: You really need something client-side like Javascript or server side to do this. HTML by itself can't work like this.

Comment: Hello @Mamen, Have you got it resolved ? If any of following answer helped you then please mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 2):

It is possible through CSS using pseudo selector

```
<html>
 <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .my-div {
        background-color: green;
        display: none;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .my-div:target {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="div1" class="my-div">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="my-div">Div 2</div>           
 </body></html>
```

Make sure you always hit with `#div1` in url e.g. [example.com/#div1](http://example.com#div1) or [example.com/#div2](http://example.com#div2) else it will show blank page

Answer (score 1):

I did this recently, don't think you can do with CSS only.

this will load correct div on page load, including when the user uses back in browser.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if (window.location.hash) {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        changeTab(hash);
      }
      else {
        changeTab('div1');
      }
    });

  function changeTab(divNo) {
    $('.divclass').hide();
    $('#' + divNo).show();
    window.location.hash = '#'+divNo;
  }

</script>
```

if you use a button to change divs just use:

```
onclick="changeTab('div1');"
```

set your div's class attribute to a type like 'divclass'

Answer (score 0):

> How to target outer div based on url?

The CSS pseudo-class `:target` is perfectly suited to this:

```css
div {
float:left;
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
}

#div1, #div2 {
display:none;
line-height: 150px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
font-size: 72px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}

#div1 {
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

#div2 {
background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}

#div1:target, #div2:target {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p><a href="#div1">Display Div1 (but not Div 2)</a></p>
<p><a href="#div2">Display Div2 (but not Div 1)</a></p>
</div>

<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
```

Comment: I answered it with same thing few hours ago.  Please avoid duplication of answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in your post you originally stated that javascript would be a better approach. Your intimation was that a CSS-only solution was somewhat hack-y. I did not think so - I thought `:target` to be an ideal solution and demonstrated it with a live example. You have since deleted your comment about javascript being the proper way to do it. Is that because you saw my post (and my example) above and decided that a CSS-only solution was probably legitimate after all?

Comment: Yes, here it is - you wrote: "I will still suggest, doing it by JS will be more proper way." My answer disagrees with your statement and fully endorses a CSS-only approach.

Comment: If you think my answer is right but suggestion about hacky thing was wrong, then commenting to right anawer would be better approach rather than reposting same answer with different opinion

Comment: I see you've edited your post again. Now, instead of saying: "It is possible through CSS you can fool users by something like below" you have decided to write: "It is possible through CSS using pseudo selector". Your original post may have preceded mine, but was rather different. Now it appears that, retrospectively, you are trying to make your earlier post much more like my later (unedited) answer. No?

Comment: default css #div1 is display block